# How can I losslessly concatenate two MP4 files and keep the telemetry information (GoPro GPMF) using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, lossless, gopro, telemetry

One may losslessly concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg as follows:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

with `list.txt`:

```
file 'C:\file1.mp4'
file 'C:\file2.mp4'
```

However, if the input files `C:\file1.mp4` and `C:\file2.mp4` have telemetry information, `output.mp4` won't have it, as `ffprobe` can confirm. In my case,
`C:\file1.mp4` and `C:\file2.mp4` have [GPMF](https://github.com/gopro/gpmf-parser)™ formatted telemetry data used within GoPro® cameras.

How can I losslessly concatenate two MP4 files and keep the telemetry information using FFmpeg?

---

`ffprobe` ouput for one of the input file with telemetry information:

```
C:\>ffprobe GX010013.MP4
ffprobe version 5.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GX010013.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2022-07-16T20:36:19.000000Z
    firmware        : H21.01.01.42.00
  Duration: 00:08:54.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 59971 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 5312x2988 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59702 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-07-16T20:36:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
      timecode        : 20:35:05:32
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-07-16T20:36:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      timecode        : 20:35:05:32
  Stream #0:2[0x3](eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-07-16T20:36:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 20:35:05:32
  Stream #0:3[0x4](eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 60 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-07-16T20:36:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 98314 for input stream 3
```

https://github.com/gopro/gpmf-parser gives an overview of the GoPro's MP4 structure:

> Telemetry carrying MP4 files will have a minimum of four tracks: Video, audio, timecode and telemetry (GPMF). A fifth track ('SOS') is used in file recovery in HERO4 and HERO5, can be ignored.
>
> File structure:
>
> ```
>   ftyp [type ‘mp41’]
>   mdat [all the data for all tracks are interleaved]
>   moov [all the header/index info]
>     ‘trak’ subtype ‘vide’, name “GoPro AVC”, H.264 video data 
>     ‘trak’ subtype ‘soun’, name “GoPro AAC”, to AAC audio data
>     ‘trak’ subtype ‘tmcd’, name “GoPro TCD”, starting timecode (time of day as frame since midnight)
>     ‘trak’ subtype ‘meta’, name “GoPro MET”, GPMF telemetry
> ```

Comment: Hi Franck. What definition of "telemetry" are you using here?  Does telemetry in this context simply mean metadata, or some sort of "phone home" thing?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket good point, here telemetry = GPMF™ formatted telemetry data used within GoPro® cameras. Specs: https://github.com/gopro/gpmf-parser

Comment: Ah thanks.  I'll take a gander at that spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51424988/395857) by [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907125/andrew), one has to add the attributes: `-map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:3 -copy_unknown -tag:2 gpmd`

Full command:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:3 -copy_unknown -tag:2 gpmd -c copy output.mp4
```

Note that https://community.gopro.com/s/question/0D53b00008BtrlQCAR/merge-files-and-keep-telemetry?language=en_US reports some issues:

> ReelSteady Go refuses to read the data.

I assume that's because `ffmpeg` is merging the `gpmd` stream roughly, since we use `-copy_unknown` because  `ffmpeg` has no clue what `gpmd` is.

However, https://goprotelemetryextractor.com/free/ seems to be able to properly extract the GPX information.