# ffmpeg - Does it communicate over internet

Tags: ffmpeg

We use the library ffmpeg in our project and based on a customer request we are trying to figure out If the library communicates over to Internet any time during the course of operations?

It will be helpful if someone can confirm this.

Comment: That info will be documented on the project documentation. Also, you could run it in a VM and sniff the traffic. We are not the FFMPEG devs. What research have you done in attempting to answer this question yourself prior to asking?

Comment: Thanks I did try wire shark, but the application I was using does a lot of streaming from cameras, and it was little tricky to check all the traffic. So I wanted to confirm if someone know about this or not. I did not see it making call in my testing, but again I was not sure if the calls is made, is it made every time or maybe once per X days?

Comment: No, you have to put the app you're testing in its own system, apart from anything else, to check. There are commands that ffmpeg supports that allow it to communicate over the network AT YOUR COMMAND. So, you're not looking for it in a prod environment, you want to look at it on its own, to see if it communicates on its own.

Comment: ffmpeg performs no network comms unless you tell it to. Do note that there can be 3rd party libs linked and called by ffmpeg. Can't speak for those but I expect the same to apply to them.

Comment: Can it? Yes. Does it meet whatever requirements your customer has? That depends on your contract and whatever auditing you have done on the way you use it. We cannot give a simple yes or no beyond vague "it has the ability" statements without you detailing your exact use cases. As the source code for ffmpeg is available it is possible for you to audit, remove all unwanted functionality and recompile your own version that cannot communicate over the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

> ffmpeg - Does it communicate over internet

That depends on which ffmpeg features one uses. Some ffmpeg features [don't](https://superuser.com/a/1733127/116475) use Internet, and some [do](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide).